# Request StateStatus from a Notary

Tags: corda

Is there any way a CorDapp can ask a Notary if a state has been consumed prior to using it in a Transaction?

Background:

I am testing `FungibleToken`’s that point to `EvolvableTokenType`’s.  Eventually the `EvolvableTokenType` changes and holders of the tokens that are not Participants of the `EvolvableTokenType` end up with states in their vault that have been unknowingly consumed.  When they try to execute a transaction involving these states the Notary will refuse to sign because it knows the states have been consumed.

I have written flows that will contact a Participant and request the missing state(s).  However it would be more efficient if I could first ask the Notary if I need to do that (i.e. if the state hasn’t been consumed I don’t need to ask a participant for an update).

Comment: This was asked again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67209670/how-to-check-state-is-consumed-or-not-to-the-notary-without-making-transaction).  See James [idea](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/tutorial-custom-notary.html#testing-your-custom-notary-service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this a couple ways.

For example, in your vault query, you could simply make sure to filter on StateStatus = UNCONSUMED. That's one way you can ensure this works the way you expect and you never get a state that won't fit your criteria.

check out this section of the docs on vaultQuery : https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/api-vault-query.html#querycriteria-interface

The other way I'd recommend that might also work is just to include this filter in your contract verification for the transaction, but doing it at the flow level just catches the problem sooner rather than later.

Comment: I understand your ideas. I am working with Reference States that are getting out of sync in some node’s vaults. These nodes can filter with StateStatus=UNCONSUMED but the state returned is actually consumed - the node just doesn’t know it. I understand Distribution Groups will eventually help me prevent this.  In the meantime I have to build my CorDapp to manage this possibility.  You have answered my question indirectly – there is nothing in the API that allows me to directly ask a Notary if a state has been consumed – the only way is to include it in a transaction and catch the failure. Thx!