# How to check state is consumed or not to the notary without making transaction

Tags: corda

I want to regularly check that output state is not consumed by tampering, so I want to ask the notary whether the state is consumed or not. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you would need to write a flow that is executed by the corda notary which then performs the vault query on the notary. This is listed as an experimental feature in the corda [docs](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/tutorial-custom-notary.html#testing-your-custom-notary-service) so you may want to rethink how you are designing your cordapp first. I haven't utilised this feature a great deal before myself so I'm unsure how well it's supported but it should work. This does mean however you are likely to be running your own corda network as you need control over how the notary is deployed.

It may be more appropriate to have another trusted node or party that has visibility and is a signer on the ContractState's that you want to check. Your third party would then also have a responder flow that performs a vault query on it's own vault and responds back to initiator.

Answer (score 1):

You can query a node for consumed states by specifying `Vault.StateStatus` in the vault query API

```
val vaultSnapshot = proxy.vaultQueryBy<ContractState>(
    QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED))
```

Comment: I thought this vaultQuery is used to check my own database. 
I am assuming tampering by own node, so I want to ask to notary.
In this case, is valutQeury correct method ?

Comment: You cannot make queries to other nodes' vaults from a node. You need to connect to the terminal of the Notary and run the query from there.

How your flows are made? If the node is observer in the flow that updates/issues/move/whatever the state, it will always be kept informed about its status and you do not need to keep asking inefficiently.